# Can't change font color on unicode character

Tags: css, unicode, colors, calendar

Really small thing, but I've got these calendar icons on my Joomla front-end edit page, on publishing buttons. I'm using the Unicode character U+1F5D2 for this, but I can't seem to change its color with CSS. I'm trying to make it white, the browser inspector says it's white, but it's clearly not.
[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTSlu.png)

I don't know if Unicode is supposed to do this, and I've never had a problem with it until I used this particular character.

The character is called by a :before on a span element with class="icon-calendar". I've tried changing the color attribute on several different levels of the element, including the :before and the span itself, but none of them take effect.

```css
#adminForm a.btn,
#adminForm button.btn {
  background-color: #0e71b8;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#adminForm button.btn:before {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Anyone know if this is supposed to happen and/or how to get around it?

Comment: The character is called by a :before on a span element with class="icon-calendar". I've tried changing the color attribute on several different levels of the element, including the :before and the span itself, but none of them take effect.

Comment: In this puush(http://puu.sh/mFaXe.png) you can see an excerpt of the inspector that shows the color setting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Looks like some unicode characters have the color, and outlines baked into them and can't be changed by css.

So the options are:

- Find alternative unicode character that can be changed in CSS
- Use font icons
- Use an image

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work using the HTML Entity.

```css
* {background: #000; font-size: 1.4em;}
.cal {color: #fff;}
```

```html
<span class="cal">&#128197;</span>
```

**Updated for :pseudo**

You should have mentioned the pseudo in your question.

Looking at your CSS you arn't targeting the `:before` pseudo

```
#adminForm a.btn:before,
#adminForm button.btn:before {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the html entity to work in the :before, which is unfortunately a necessity.

Comment: Forgot to mention that in the original question, but I already tried that :/ I'll update the original too.

Comment: This is your first time on stackoverflow, you should really read how to create an answerable question by showing what you've tried and enough code for us to recreate your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this doesnt seem to work at all. the calendar icon is still gray - not white.  
At least in Chrome and Firefox. IEdge is drawing a white calendar icon.
I dislike those colorful emoji-icons - turning computer-typography on its head ...

Answer (score 0):

Bart,

Problem without font-family or depend your Base CSS Normalize, but you can try ur code "Fonts Googleapis" is work font-face to change a color. Sorry bad english.

See:
[http://codepen.io/KingRider/pen/QGeMoQ](http://%63%6f%64%65pen.io/KingRider/pen/QGeMoQ)

Why not try plugin 'Font Awesome' is best

http://fontawesome.io/examples/