# Pseudo Class Color Change on Hover

Tags: css

I have an accordion where upon hover, the text color changes. Sounds simple enough, but I have an issue with the content within a pseudo class changing color. I feel like I've added the `:after:hover` class in the to change the color, but it's not working? Any reason why?

There's a more detailed Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/devin1229/pen/dyZNOdm).

```
<div class="task-resources-accordion">
  Title
</div>
<div class="task-resources-accordion-panel">
  <div class="task-resources-accordion-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
/* Accordions */

.task-resources-accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.task-resources-accordion.active,
.task-resources-accordion:hover {
  background-color: #21bfb2;
  color: #fff;
}

.task-resources-accordion:after {
  content: "\2795";
  font-size: 13px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.task-resources-accordion:after:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.task-resources-accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
  color: #fff;
}

.task-resources-accordion-panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.task-resources-accordion-panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.task-resources-accordion-content {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some unicodes css properties are not changeable, and you picked one of those. Try a different code and as of css3 you have to use double colons, but that won't fix your problem, just a FYI. See [this pen][1] that I copied from yours for the fix. https://codepen.io/javascript-examples/pen/jOayVgq

```
<div class="task-resources-accordion">
  Title
</div>
<div class="task-resources-accordion-panel">
  <div class="task-resources-accordion-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
 /* Accordions */

 .task-resources-accordion {
 background-color: #eee;
 color: #1e1e1e;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 18px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: left;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 transition: 0.4s ease;
 font-family: "AleckCdBold", sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 0;
 }

 .task-resources-accordion.active,
 .task-resources-accordion:hover {
  background-color: #21bfb2;
  color: #fff;
 }

.task-resources-accordion::after {
 content: "\002B";
 font-size: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;

 }

.task-resources-accordion::after:hover {
 content: "\002B";
 color: #fff;
 }

.task-resources-accordion.active::after {
 content: "\2212";
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 }

.task-resources-accordion-panel {
 padding: 0 18px;
 background-color: white;
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: 0.4s ease;
 opacity: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 }

 .task-resources-accordion-panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 1000px;
  }

 .task-resources-accordion-content {
  padding: 15px;
  }
```

Comment: Oh wow, I never knew that. Thanks!

Comment: It could really throw you down a rabbit hole because some properties are changeable. It makes you think that you've done something wrong when it comes to changing the color because you were already able to change the size.

Answer (score 0):

Use 1 more colon with after and correct the position of hover like:
`task-resources-accordion:hover::after`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are using unicode in content. Its color cannot be changed by css.
[Can't change font color on unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943861/cant-change-font-color-on-unicode-character)